# c program not accepting parsed input

Tags: c, bash

Hi I have a c program that takes in two numbers and adds them. very simple and just learning c here. however i have a csv file with two columns that I have parsed with a bash script, and piping that into the c program does not yield a result. For example if I *manually* type in:

```
$ ./adder 1 2
$ 3
```

and then my bash program parses as follows

```
$ ./parser test.csv 
$ 1 2
```

where at present there is just one line in the csv file. i.e. exactly the same input to the c file as before

then doing:

```
$ ./parser | ./ adder
$
```

I get no result.

what is going on here?

Comment: There's an extra space between `./` and `adder`. Did you really type that into the terminal?

Comment: Add to your question the exact value of the `test.csv` file. Also, add the code where you parse the file.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, you're piping the output of ./parser to ./adder, not the output of ./parser test.csv.  Presumably, your parser requires a file to parse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `$ ./adder 1 2` you are passing `1 2` as command line arguments to the program, which are available in `argv[]`.

But with `$ ./parser | ./ adder` the output of `parser` is passed as input to `adder` i.e if `adder` tries to read from standard input - `stdin` (using functions like `scanf`, `gets` etc) , it will get that as input.

If your program is not reading from standard input, it will not get those.

If you want to make it work, on linux use `xargs` as

```
 $ ./parser | xargs ./adder
```

Comment: @ Rohan thanks very much this works for me. Fortunately I am using Linux too!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like adder accepts numbers in command line, and in the pipe you try to feed the numbers in standard input. You should be able to achieve what you want with xargs:

```
./parser | xargs ./adder
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `xargs` to read the output of one program into the command-line aruments of the next.

Pipes redirect *stdout* to *stdin*. stdin is different than entering your arguments on a command-line. xargs allows you to convert stdin (created by a pipe) to command-line arguments. Try this:

```
./parser | xargs ./adder
```

You can mentally read this as: "The output of parser is used as the arguments to adder."